# how to make my website secured

Tags: php, javascript

i have a **php code** inside my website to a quotation form that has 
**java script** for making

```
 name , telephone number and email
```

rquired fields  before submiting the form and its working fine but a few day ago i found that someone is sending me alot of junk for that form and he send the form empty is that means that he could access my files i mean like hacking or how he could do that

```
<form id="forma" method="post" action="quatation.php"> 

        <div id="infoq">
          <label id="namelab" for="namea"><span>* </span><?php _e ("Name", "my_theme");?></label> 
            <input  type="text" name="namea" id="namea" value="" size="22" tabindex="1" class="rounded" required aria-required='true' pattern="^([a-zA-Z\u0600-\u06ff\ufb50-\ufdff\ufe70-\ufeff]+)$" title="Your name (no special characters, diacritics are okay)"
                 spellcheck="false"/> <br />

        <label id="emaillb" for="email"><span>* </span><?php _e ("Email", "my_theme");?></label> 
<input type="email" name="email" id="email" value="" size="22" tabindex="2" class="rounded" required aria-required='true' 
pattern="^(([-\w\d]+)(\.[-\w\d]+)*@([-\w\d]+)(\.[-\w\d]+)*(\.([a-zA-Z]{2,5}|[\d]{1,3})){1,2})$"
                title="Your email address" spellcheck="false" /> <br />

            <label id="phonelb" for="phonea"><span>* </span>Phone</label>
```

*  
                 
                
 
            
         
this is the form but the problem is when i used to put the quatation.php file in the theme file it gives me error

Not Found
The requested URL /quatation.php was not found on this server

so i put it outside could that be the reason ?

Comment: If you are in doubt of your coding skills, it's easier to use a plugin like [Contact Form 7](http://wordpress.org/plugins/contact-form-7/) to create your form.

Answer (score 4):

It may possible that he is trying to hack. I am sure you are storing form data after escaping/sanitizing  the content which eliminate the risk of Sql injection

[image]

and since user can submit empty form it mean you haven done the server side validation. what you need to check is

1. First check that weather field is set or not
2. name can only contain latter for example [a-zA-Z] (for english)
3. phone number can only contain digit [0-9]
4. validate email formate (you can also use `FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL`)
5. use captcha code (Google's [recaptcha](http://www.google.com/recaptcha/captcha) is quite good)

**Good Read**

1. [Validating Sanitizing and Escaping User Data](http://codex.wordpress.org/Validating_Sanitizing_and_Escaping_User_Data)
2. [Data Validation](http://codex.wordpress.org/Data_Validation)
3. [**Chris Shiflett : security articles**](http://shiflett.org/articles) (heighly recomended reading)

Comment: Never used but you can also use plugin like 
[Contact Form 7](http://wordpress.org/plugins/contact-form-7/) but i highly recommend  reading source code of plugin first to know what exactly its doing

Comment: i am realy sorry but i am a beginner what do you mean by "First check that weather field is set or not" and i added my code so you can see it and i wanted to know if it could be the problem that the quotation.php is not inside the content folder

Comment: do server side validation .. and my first is exactly what 
Puggan Se is telling

Answer (score 1):

you need the same checks, coded in php, at the php that recives the post-data from the form.

a simple version could be:

```
if(!isset($_POST['name']) OR strlen(isset($_POST['name'])) < 4)
{
    die("Name is required to be at least 4 character long.\n");
}
if(!isset($_POST['telephone number']) OR strlen(isset($_POST['telephone number'])) < 4)
{
    die("telephone number is required to be at least 4 character long.\n");
}
if(!isset($_POST['email']) OR strlen(isset($_POST['email'])) < 4)
{
    die("email is required to be at least 4 character long.\n");
}
```

Comment: checking weather set or not isnt the only thing to care

Comment: It's a good start, the list of things to do to protect yourself is long, you added a bit more, but it could also include checking the against blacklist, spam filtering like Akismet, time mesurments, and captcha

Comment: where i could add this code ? to function.php ?

Comment: your forms action-attribute says the reciver is the quatation.php

Comment: yes do you mean i should add something like this to qutation.php

Comment: heey guys thaaanks alot for trying to help me i found that the problem is that he could see my code when using view page source and by this ways he edit the code and remove the javascript part so he could make the foeld not not required is there a way to hide this part of my code to stop any one from playing in my code

Comment: Hide your code is the wrong path, hiding the code just hides the problems, they are still there, and a bit of guesswork and your as vulnerable as before, update you code like @NullPoiиteя suggested, the code I wrote above just solves his/her first point, start there and read about the rest of the points. Hiding code is used for 2½ reasons, by virus-makers, to hide the code from anti-virus software, and proprietary coding to protect it from being copied. the last case is to make the code shorter, to increase transfer speed.